# Compare time in MilliSecond

Tags: c++, linux

I want to check time in milli second to do a specific task in server client architecture?
For example, Server have to send message to a client say m1 at 1800 mili second, how it has been done?

Answer (score 1):

Use gettimeofday routine. It gives you the time in microseconds granularity. This is the best you can get in C.

```
     gettimeofday(&tv1, NULL);//Init
     .....
     gettimeofday(&tv2, NULL);//Final
     printf("\nTime:%ld usec", ((tv2.tv_sec-tv1.tv_sec)*1000000 + tv2.tv_usec-tv1.tv_usec));
```

PS:
I assume you need info for C. Please provide details of what you have attempted when asking a question.